# What steps in Fedora to build a source rpm of newer odb off git?

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild, odb

Fedora 23 provides the odb-2.4.0 package.
This git repo

```
git://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/odb.git
```

is probably where a fedora-modified copy of the sources exist.

The upstream git repo exists here

```
git://scm.codesynthesis.com/odb/odb.git
```

I need the newer upstream version which doesn't crash for some code i have, while odb 2.4 does.

How can I go about building and installing the newer version, and potentially, after more commits in upstream, rebuild and reinstall the newer version?
Do I make a source rpm and install on my machine, and another with an identical fedora?

I am reading

```
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package
```

but I do not need to deploy this package to fedora, i just would use the RPM mechanism to facilitate installing unreleased versions?

Can I use COPR for that, add my own repo, and install from it instead?
In COPR, can I reuse the SPEC file from the odb2.4.0 rpm and update it to the newer odb?

Comment: You can obtain Fedora's own source RPM, and update your copy of it to build the version you want.  Look in [Koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/).  You will have a bit of a learning curve, but it will be a lot easier to start from an existing SRPM than to perform the packaging from scratch.

Comment: but how do I change the source code inside the SRPM to come instead from a clone of the upstream odb git repo?

Comment: Source RPMs include the source.  You do not rewrite the contents to somehow grab the sources from somewhere else; rather, you grab the sources you want yourself (normally as a compressed archive), put them on your system where `rpmbuild` can find them, and update the spec file to name the new source archive.  I recommend you find and study one of the RPM-building tutorials available on the web.  The details are too long and too case-specific for SO.  Google is your friend.